# Using "IN" CQL function in Geoserver Cross-Layer Filtering

Tags: geoserver

I've two layers "cities" (has the fields: fid, code, and geom) and "cities_details" (has the fields: id, city_code, and area).

I need to filter "cities" layer with a condition applied on the "cities_details" layer. I believe that Geoserver's Cross-layer Filtering extension can do that.

The following CQL filter runs successfully:

`code = querySingle('cities_details', 'city_code','area = 5000')`
It returns the city with area = 5000.

But the following CQL filter failed:

`code IN (queryCollection('cities_details', 'city_code','area >= 5000'))`

I tried also the following, but didn't work:

`code IN (collectGeometries(queryCollection('cities_details', 'city_code','area >= 5000')))`

In both cases the log tells:
org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: Could not parse CQL filter list

Can anybody help me, how to use "IN" with the Cross-Layer Filtering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because "IN" requires an explicit list of values, and given OGC Filter has no notion of "in", so something like `a in (1, 2)` translates down (before being evaluated) to `a = 1 OR a = 2`.

So your example translates down to `code = queryCollection('cities_details', 'city_code','area >= 5000')`, which of course does not work.

Now, to support multi-valued properties in complex features it's nowadays possible to do something like "collection = value", where the semantic is driven by a MatchAction that luckily for you defaults to "MatchAny", so if any item in the list matches the value, it should return true.

In other words, while I have not tried, it may be that using `queryCollection('cities_details', 'city_code','area >= 5000') = code` is going to work (was not really intended to, and as said I did not try, but there is a chance it might work for you).

If that does not work, the only other option that I can think of is to write java code and create a inList function that would accept a list of values, see this tutorial:
http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/function.html

Comment: Thanks a lot Andrea for your reply, but unfortunately it didn't work. I tried it as both CQL and OGC filters but didn't work. Do you have any turn around solution?

Comment: I've edited my answer.

Comment: Do you mean I should modify the Geoserver's source code?

Comment: Correct. There is a guide here:http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/function.html

Comment: And this new user defined function can be called from CQL filter from Geoserver normally, right?

Comment: Exactly, every properly registered function (see tutorial) should be callable from CQL like any other already existing function